# End to end test for Passkey in mobile App

Tags: android, ios, automated-tests, android-testing, passkey

[Passkey](https://fidoalliance.org/passkeys/) requires an [Authenticator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticator#FIDO2) to store and validate the credentials during registration and authentication phase.
This requires user-presence and user-verification depending on the Relying Party implementation.

I'm implementing Passkeys for a mobile application and wondering if having automated end to end tests is possible because of the user interaction requirements?

While searching I found that for Selenium, there's[virtual authenticator](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/virtual_authenticator/) which we can use for browsers; however, couldn't find anything for native mobile apps.

Is it possible to implement end to test in mobile apps for Passkeys for android or iOS?